# java.lang.Long has no persistent id property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to persist entities from a 3rd party library to a database, so I am using the `orm.xml` approach, rather than using Java persistence annotations.

My `orm.xml` file looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <description>External entities</description>
    <package>org.zendesk.client.v2.model</package>
    <mapped-superclass class="org.zendesk.client.v2.model.Request">
        <attributes>
            <embedded-id name="id"></embedded-id>
        </attributes>
    </mapped-superclass>
    <entity class="Ticket">
        <pre-update method-name="update" />

        <attributes>    

            <id name="id">
                <generated-value/>
            </id>

        </attributes>     
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Yet, when I run the above, I get the following error:

```
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:96)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.createEntityManagerFactory(JpaEndpoint.java:510)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.getEntityManagerFactory(JpaEndpoint.java:223)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.validate(JpaEndpoint.java:503)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaEndpoint.createProducer(JpaEndpoint.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:439)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.Long has no persistent id property: org.zendesk.client.v2.model.Ticket.id
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2478)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2164)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:733)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 84 more
```

#### Ticket.java

```
public class Ticket extends Request implements SearchResultEntity {
    private String externalId;
    private Type type;
    private Priority priority;
    private String recipient;
    private Long submitterId;
    private Long assigneeId;
    private Long groupId;
    private List<Long> collaboratorIds;
    private List<Collaborator> collaborators;
    private Long forumTopicId;
    private Long problemId;
    private boolean hasIncidents;
    private Date dueAt;
    private List<String> tags;
    private List<CustomFieldValue> customFields;
    private SatisfactionRating satisfactionRating;
    private List<Long> sharingAgreementIds;
    private List<Long> followupIds;
    private Long ticketFormId;
    private Long brandId;
}
```

#### Request.java

```
public class Request {
    protected Long id;
    protected String url;
    protected String subject;
    protected String description;
    protected Status status;
    protected Ticket.Requester requester;
    protected Long requesterId;
    protected Long organizationId;
    protected Via via;
    protected Date createdAt;
    protected Date updatedAt;
    protected Comment comment;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post your `org.zendesk.client.v2.model.Ticket` class

Comment: org.zendesk.client.v2.model.Ticket is not my class. It is a 3rd party class, hence I am using xml rather than annotations.

Comment: What does your persistence.xml look like?

Comment: you cannot declare field "id" in Ticket when it is in Request. Put the field "id" in Request as an "id" not "embedded-id".

Comment: I think your problem has somethingto do with the <embedded-id name="id"></embedded-id> on super-class and <id name="id"> on your ticket class.

Comment: @Michal - yes, I think you are right. I have been taking a trial-n-error approach, but have yet to find a solution that does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring fields in XML metadata, you can only define them in the metadata for the class that they occur in, so in your case the field "*id*" should be defined for class `Request` (not `Request` **and** `Ticket`). Also you should define it as type "*id*" in Request not "*embedded-id*".

The only time you can also define field "*id*" in the metadata for class `Ticket` is when using *attribute-override* to override particular parts of metadata.